# XML data text + binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-serialization

I built an iPhone app that is getting information from a server (this is also a server that I built).
The data from the server is `XML` and I use the XML parser to parse the message.
What I want is to add an image to be sent from the server, and I am asking if I can add binary data of such an image to the XML message. For example 10 tags will be text and 1 tag will be binary (the image). So when the XML parser gets to the binary tag, it inserts the data to `NSDATA` object and the rest of the tags will be inserted to `NSString`.

Does the XML parser of `Cocoa` can handle this situation?

If not, what do you think will be the easiest way to do this with one connection to the server so that the data from the server is sent once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer binary data wrapped in XML, encode it using e.g. Base64, which turns your binary data into characters that won't mess up your XML.

Comment: does i need to convert it back to binary or i can put the Base64 to the initWithdata for the image?

Comment: can you tell me how to decode it ? i saw some examples in the net but its look to complicated

Comment: I'm sorry; my knowledge of Objective-C and its libraries is zero :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the image data, encoded using Base64. There is this NSData category by Matt Gallagher that adds Base64 decoding support to NSData (dateFromBase64String). You can find it on his [Cocoa with love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) website.

Mind you that encoding images in Base64 adds about 33% in file size.